# Parsing SMS PDU

Tags: android, parsing, sms, pdu

Seems to be that I need to parse PDU byte array received during SMS BroadcastReceiver:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{ 
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
}
```

Can someone point me how to do it?

I know that PDUs can be handled using `SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i])` but it's not what I'm looking for. I need more precise control over pdu bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found solution - there's nice Java and dot NET library (under Apache license), which handles all PDU related stuff - parsing and so on. It's [SMSLib](http://smslib.org/)

Comment: given link is broken.. hope we can use this https://code.google.com/archive/p/smslib/downloads

Comment: can also be found at https://github.com/tdelenikas/smslib, though it says the project is no longer maintained.

Answer (score -1):

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

    SmsMessage[] msgs = null;

    if (bundle == null) return;

    Object[] pdus =  (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

    msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
    smsCount = msgs.length;
    String originalAddress;
    String tmpSmsBody;
    for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
        msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);

        // Original Address
        originalAddress = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();

        // Message body
        tmpSmsBody= msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
    }                
}
```

Comment: please read my question carefully. I know about function createFromPdu() - it's not what I'm looking for!

Comment: @barmaley If you want even more precise control, you should parse it by your own. You can search for the SMS standart.