# Get message thread id or _id from onReceive android

Tags: android, sms

I have tried to get a message id which is saved in phone.
But I failed to get it.
My existing code is here

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String address = "";
    String message = "";
    String msg_id="";
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        Object[] smsExtra = (Object[]) extras.get("pdus");

        for (int i = 0; i < smsExtra.length; i++) {
            SmsMessage sms = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) smsExtra[i]);
            message += sms.getMessageBody();
            address = sms.getOriginatingAddress();
        }
        sms = new Sms(msg_id,message, address);
        UploadSms up = new UploadSms();
        up.start();
        Toast.makeText(context,
                "SMS Received>>" + message + "From >>" + address,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

By this I get sms body and sender number.
But I know there exist a unique number for every message in android phone, I retrieved it.
But unable to retrieved in onReceive methods.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will have to parse the SMS PDU (in the raw PDU format) since at the android application layer there exists no API to retrieve the user data header. I believe that the short message identifier resides within the User Data Header (Octet 1). Please refer to the post [Parsing SMS PDU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663257/parsing-sms-pdu).

In that post one of the users mentions a freeware by the name 'SMSLib' (under APACHE License) in order to parse and extract the message parameters. The message ID could be extracted using the method getMessageId() - Method in class org.smslib.Message.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How can I get SMS ID from SMSMessage ?

Comment: @osimerpothe you can't you have to figure it out by the address of the sms

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if this suffices for your purposes, but the [`SMSMessage.getIndexOnICC()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsMessage#getIndexOnIcc()) method returns an `int`, indexed from 1 (up to presumably `Integer.MAX_VALUE`) which is the unique identifier for the `SMSMessage` assigned by the smart card/ICC. It can also return -1 if the `SMSMessage` was synthesized opposed to processed through the ICC.

Instead of synthesizing using the PDU, you should probably be using [`Telephony.Sms.Intents#getMessagesFromIntent(Intent)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.Sms.Intents#getMessagesFromIntent(android.content.Intent)) to grab a list of the `SMSMessage`s via the PDUs using an API call instead of rolling your own. However, that was added in API 19 and so it may not be supported depending on your API version.

If you want to roll your own, the current version (API 30 at the time of writing, though the link is to the master so it may change) of the `getMessageFromIntent(Intent)` source code can be viewed [here](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/provider/Telephony.java;l=1356;bpv=0;bpt=1) for inspiration of how to do things without using the API (if you want to do that for some reason). It seems that the proper way to synthesize an `SMSMessage` is actually the way you are doing it though, at least for the most part. Though you really should be using `SMSMessage.createFromPdu(byte[], String)` and specifying the format you get from `Intent.getStringExtra("format")`, as otherwise you may run into problems depdending on how the message is formatted (for example you might find both formats on multi-sim devices).

If you want to get really low-level and parse things out yourself, you should look to the CDMA and GSM specific implementations of `SMSMessage` (though this is not a subclass to be clear), which are of course android internal and not meant to be used as exposed APIs. The CDMA implementation for parsing the PDU is at [`...cdma.SMSMessage.parsePdu(byte[])`](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/telephony/java/com/android/internal/telephony/gsm/SmsMessage.java;l=1198;drc=master) whereas the GSM implementation is at [`...gsm.SMSMessage.parsePdu(byte[])`](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/telephony/java/com/android/internal/telephony/gsm/SmsMessage.java;drc=master;bpv=1;bpt=1;l=1198). For reference to the underlying base class you should see [`SMSMessageBase`](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/telephony/java/com/android/internal/telephony/SmsMessageBase.java;drc=master;bpv=1;bpt=1;l=36).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll tell you my purpose. Whenever any text SMS in my Android device (API 21 to 30) will come, Broadcast receiver onReceive will be called, and it'll be stored in Android Telephony database with some unique id, right? I want that ID. Request you to give answer with proper code.

Comment: You can probably search through the `Telephony.SMS.*` implementations of `Telephony.TextBasedSmsColumns`, which extends `BaseColumns`, which provides a constant called `_ID` which is the unique row identifier for a given SMS message (or MMS message depending on which class is used, there are MMS views as well). Note that this isn't anything to do with the SMS/MMS standards, but rather a unique identifier, likely of the internal database row though that is an impl. detail. See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.Sms.Conversations Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: See the fetchInbox() here: https://github.com/amjadz/Text-Message/blob/master/yama/app/src/main/java/edu/uw/amjadz/yama/MainActivity.kt | I exactly implemented this code. But this issue is when any new message will come I want to read all row (or read all SMS) to get that particular new Arrived SMS Unique ID. And that will be little heavy operation  So I just want to get that particular ID only!

Comment: You need to use the `Telephony.SMS.Inbox.URI` instead of hard-coding it. Also, instead of using a query with a bunch of `null` values and iterating over every value in the entire rowset, try specifying those `null` parameters. There is a `selection` parameter which expects an SQL `WHERE` clause. Just write a properly formatted `WHERE` clause and the database will only return the items you selected. That stops you from having to iterate the whole rowset. Make sure you use the `?` overloading by providing the `selectionArgs` arg (populated using `SMSMessage`) instead of `String` concatenation.